# MongoDB: level up array without unwind

Tags: mongodb, nosql, aggregation-framework

I have to aggregate one collection in the MongoDB.

The thing is: pull up one array to one level up and make some kind unwind on it.

I have collection like this:

```js
{
 "name": "some_name", 
 "pair": [
  {
   "product": "prod1",
   "brands": [
    "coca-cola",
    "pepsi",
    "adidas"
   ]
  }
  ,
  {
   "product": "prod2",
   "brands": [
    "nike",
    "reebok",
   ]
  }  
 ]
}
```

And after aggregation I would like to see info like this:

```js
{
 "name": "some_name", 
 "pair": [
  {
   "product": "prod1",
   "brands": "coca-cola",
  }
  ,
  {
   "product": "prod1",
   "brands": "pepsi",
  }
  ,
  {
   "product": "prod1",
   "brands": "adidas",
  }
  ,
  {
   "product": "prod2",
   "brands": "nike",
  }
  ,
  {
   "product": "prod2",
   "brands": "reebok",
  }
 ]
}
```

I.e. we will get array pair: where element contain document with product and brand.

Thank for help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below aggregation as well

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
    "pair": {
      "$reduce": {
        "input": {
          "$map": {
            "input": "$pair",
            "as": "sd",
            "in": {
              "$map": {
                "input": "$$sd.brands",
                "in": { "product": "$$sd.product", "brands": "$$this" }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "initialValue": [],
        "in": { "$concatArrays": ["$$value", "$$this"] }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```